# I can't see Google Calendar on macOS Calendar app

Tags: macos, calendar, ical, google-calendar, google-sync

I have had some sync issue with my Google calendars and my iPhone / iPad / macOS calendar app, so I have decided to try to fix it.

I removed / added my Google Account from my iPhone and now I can see the calendar without issue. The problem is with Calendar desktop application (on macOS).

I followed all the instructions but while I can see Google listed on iCal, I can't see my Google calendars (check the picture).

[image]

I've tried all the instructions on Google's support pages but without success.

What else can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try to move your cursor over the "Google" label (shown in your screenshot) to check if you did not accidentally tap the "hide" button which only appears in this situation? There should be a "show" option appearing if your Google account is functional.

---

**Edit:**

If previous didn’t work try to quit Calendar and to delete device caches:

- In Finder click on the "Go" menu, hold `alt` and tap "Library"
- Go to "Caches" and remove all folders

Then remove Calendar data:

- While still in "Library" folder remove all files and folders in "Calendar"

Be sure to backup this last folder before doing anything as it contains your personal data. Launch Calendar app and see if it worked, if not do not forget to refill Calendar data with your backup.

Comment: Yes, I did it but nothing change. (Except for the label show hide). Still empty list.

Comment: Can you clarify your question by listing what you already tried? (like logging off the account, rebooting your computer etc...)

Comment: Sure, I have removed the account from System Preferences -> Accounts, the I have verified the "Google" label was not visible on iCal then I have added it again.

Comment: Hum, last suggestion: try to quit Calendar and to delete you cache (in the Mac Library Cache Folder) as well as Calendar information (in Library > Calendar). Be sure to backup this data in case it doesn’t work (this folder contains all your events: iCloud, Google, local ones...).

Comment: Ok, this worked. I removed the cache (~/Library/Calendars), remove the Google account, restart, create a new Google account and restart the iCal. Tnx for the suggestions! If you update the answer I will be more then happy to make it as Solution

Comment: Post edited! Your welcome.

Comment: can you explain how to delete these folders? I have the same issue.

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific. @David天宇Wong

Comment: Edit notes didn't work for me, but only because it misses details which can be found in link provided in other answer: https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-the-iCal-Cache
(we also need to clear the Trash, and kill CalendarAgent - having that after calendar restart my accounts were discovered)

Comment: Ah!  Deleting those files worked! Thanks so much for this! Spent multiple hours with Apple support yesterday trying to figure this out and I kept asking them (since adding the calendars worked in a fresh account) if there were like prefs files or something I could delete and they said no (multiple times). You nailed it!

Answer (score 13):

You need to tick the calendar in your [synchronization settings](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect).

Comment: I know this answer is incomplete, but I don't think it deserves a downvote. It was, actually, the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: This is the real answer. I always forget this url.

Comment: This was how I was able to sync my "Other Calendar" to my macOS Calendar.  Also described here: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358

Answer (score 6):

This is a pretty bad problem that Apple hasn't fixed yet. You need to delete the calendar cache, [see here on how to do that](https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-the-iCal-Cache).

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the workaroud was to go to System Preferences > Internet Accounts and click on the relevant accounts that were not syncing. Turns out even though the accounts were listed there (and in the Calendar app), the accounts were not authenticated and just needed a password.

Comment: this was the case for me

Answer (score 0):

I just landed on this post from a google search after this exact issue. What solved it for me was simply selecting the google calendar as default. The other answers didn't lead to it showing up.